# laravel about How to obtain Additional Data by Yajra\DataTables (Additional Data Response)

Tags: laravel, datatable, response

The following site explains how to send data from the server, but not how to retrieve data on the front-end side. How can I retrieve the data on the front-end side?

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/response-with

```
use DataTables;

Route::get('user-data', function() {
    $model = App\User::query();

    return DataTables::eloquent($model)
                ->with('posts', 100)
                ->with('comments', 20)
                ->toJson();
});
```

Example Response

```
    {
        "draw": 1,
        "recordsTotal": 10,
        "recordsFiltered": 3,
        "data": [{
          ----＼(^o^)／------
        }],
        "posts": 100,   <----this (^o^)I want to get it on the blade side.
        "comments": 20  <----this (^o^)I want to get it on the blade side.
 }
```

BLADE SIDE (I want to use the data when describing the footer.)

```
"footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {

 　　　　　　　＼(^o^)／I want to get it here.

}
```

Other

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    // searching: false,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "{{ route(´ε｀ ) }}",
        data: function(d) {
            d.search = $('#search').val();
        },
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            return data;

　　　　　　　　　　　＼(^o^)／I tried my best here.

                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(json.posts);

　　　　　　　　　　　＼(^o^)／The posts data exists.
　　　　　　　　　　　　　
        }
    },
    columns: [{
    }],
    responsive: true,
    stateSave: true,
    lengthMenu: [
        [7, 10, 15, -1],
        [7, 10, 15, "All"]
    ],
    displayLength: 15,
    // scrollX: true,
    // scrollY: 200,
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {

 　　　　　　　　　＼(^o^)／I want to get it here.

            console.log(row);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(start);
            console.log(end);
            console.log(display);

　　　　　　　　　(；´Д｀)　Not found..
    },
    "createdRow": function(row, data, key) {
    },

}); $('#example').on('click', 'button.myShow', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = oTable.row(tr);
    console.log(row.data()); });

$('#search_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    oTable.draw();
    e.preventDefault(); }); });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you catch the data. I think you can catch it inside `footerCallback` as well.

Example:

```
initComplete: function (data) {
    console.log(data.json.posts)
    console.log(data.json.comments)
}
```

Comment: for cases when you use e.g. `table.page(page_).draw(false)` it wont enter `initComplete` 
  The  `drawCallback` is more preferable for most redrawings. Has same `data` argument passed through.